# customize ng-bootstrap NgbTypeahead display

Tags: ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have been trying to incorporate ngbootstrap into my angular 5 application particularly typeahead. I got it working with simple example but I would like to format the dropdown shown with result as below[customise typeahead result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez0lz.png).

Is it possible to have categories and different tabs in the typeahead result output?